# Is there a way to capture all functional interfaces of a certain type?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Assume I have the following hand-crafted functional interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public static interface OnHandCardAddedListener extends HandView {
    @Override
    void onCardAdded(final Card card);

    @Override
    default void onCardPlayed(final int cardIndex) { }

    @Override
    default void onCardsSwapped(final int cardIndexOne, final int cardIndexTwo) { }
}
```

It is of the signature `Card -> void`, hence an implementation for this functional interface is a lambda that is an implementation of the `Consumer<Card>` functional interface.

I know that I perhaps should extend `Consumer<Card>` and implement the `apply` with a default method in the `OnHandCardAddedListener` interface.

But why does it not just work out of the box?

Testing with the following:

```
private void acceptConsumer(final Consumer<Card> cardConsumer) {

}
```

and testcode:

```
Consumer<Card> cardConsumer = card -> { };
acceptConsumer(cardConsumer);
OnHandCardAddedListener viewCardConsumer = card -> { };
acceptConsumer(viewCardConsumer); // does not compile
```

Here `acceptConsumer(viewCardConsumer)` does not compile, but why does it not compile? As far as I can see they should resolve to the same type of lambda, hence both be allowed for both concrete definitions.

**Edit**, I forgot to mention why this would be important, consider the case where I need to use a functional interface that has **not** been provided by *java.util.function*, then we can see that two clients need to real out their own concrete functional interface which does the same.
Hence a way is needed to generalize its usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that you have already assigned a type to your lambda expression.

Consider this example:

```
acceptConsumer(card -> {});
```

Here, the compiler can check what the type of the argument is supposed to be. Since the lambda provided is a legal representation of that argument type, all is well.
Compare this to your example:

```
OnHandCardAddedListener viewCardConsumer = card -> { };
acceptConsumer(viewCardConsumer); // does not compile
```

Here you are not passing a lambda to the method, but a totally different type than is expected. The fact that you use a lambda expression to initialize `viewCardConsumer` is completely irrelevant. This code is equivalent to the following code which I don't think you would expect to compile:

```
OnHandCardAddedListener viewCardConsumer = new OnHandCardAddedListener() {
    @Override
    void onCardAdded(final Card card){  };
};
acceptConsumer(viewCardConsumer); // does not compile either
```

Comment: Yes. The shorthand for this is "structural" typing vs "nominal" typing. Even though both lambdas are functions that consume a Card and return void, one is of type `Consumer<Card>` and the other is of type `OnHandCardAddedListener`. These types are incompatible, ergo, compile-time error.

Answer (score 2):

Try (untested):

```
acceptConsumer(viewCardConsumer::onCardAdded);
```

**Edit:**

> why does this work and the other not?

One is a plain old Java method call and OnHandCardAddedListener doesn't extend Consumer. The provided solution is a method reference which has its own rules: only input and output parameter (and exceptions?) have to match.

Comment: This does work indeed, but why does this work and the other not?

Comment: It does work, but using a method reference to represent a different functional interface is an extremely confusing way to (ab)use them, so it should definitely be avoided.

Comment: I see some use cases for static method references, but I, too, am not sure what are good cases you would want to use non-static method references.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the possibility if it was the other way around:

```
Consumer<Card> viewCardConsumer = card -> { };
acceptConsumer(viewCardConsumer);

private void acceptConsumer(final OnHandCardAddedListener<Card> cardConsumer) {
    cardConsumer.onCardPlayed(1);
}
```

If we follow your initial thought that this should be possible, then we quickly encounter a problem: `viewCardConsumer` (which is a `Consumer<Card>`) does not have an `onCardPlayed` method!

The same goes for the example in your case,

```
private void acceptConsumer(final Consumer<Card> cardConsumer) {
    cardConsumer.apply(new Card());
}
```

If you would pass `OnHandCardAddedListener` to this method, it does not contain an `apply` method.

Given these examples, I wouldn't expect it to - neither would I want it to - work "out of the box".